# Is a polynomial also a covering map?

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

**Question**: Let $p(z)$ be a polynomial over $\mathbb{C}$. Is it true that $p:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is a covering map ?

**Partial answer**: Let us look first at the points where $p'(z)\ne 0$. There the inverse function theorem tells us much more -- that $p$ is locally invertible, and the inverse is in fact holomorphic.

At the points where $p'(z) = 0$, however, $p$ will not be $1-1$ in any neighborhood, and certainly we cannot find an open neighborhood $U$ such that $p^{-1}(U)$ is a family of disjoint open sets, each homeomorphic to $U$.

Is the reasoning correct ? any comments are welcome.

Comment: Yes. If the degree of $p$ is not $1$, then $p$ will never be a covering map. However, for degree greater than $1$, if you remove the bad points, then you do get a covering map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. $p$ defines instead a [branched cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branched_covering).

Answer (score 1):

The above answers are suffice for the purpose. I just want to remark that any polynomial $p(z)$ can be transformed by a suitable biholomorphic coordinate transformation $z=f(w)$ into $q(w)=w^{n}$(can you fill the detail yourself?). So you only need to deal with simple power maps.

Comment: OK, do you have a ref. for deriving that biholomorphic transformation ?

Comment: Hint: search "fundamental theorem of algebra" and "winding number".

Comment: @Teddy: I don't think this is true. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/474038/completing-the-cube)