# "completing the cube"

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

Given a quadratic polynomial $p(z) = z^2 +a z +b$ in $\mathbb{C}[x]$, we can "complete the square" to write $p(z) = g(f(z)^2)$ where $f,g$ are translations.
\begin{align*}
f(z) = z + a/2 && g(z) = z+ b - a^2/4
\end{align*}
In particular, $f,g$ are <strike>entire diffeomorphisms</strike> *homeomorphisms* of $\mathbb{C}$.

> **Question:** Given a monic degree 3 polynomial $p(z)$ with complex coefficients, is it always possible to find <strike>entire diffeomorphisms</strike> *homeomorphisms* $f,g$ of $\mathbb{C}$ such that $p(z) = g( f(z)^3)$?

It the answer is yes, how explicit can the maps $f,g$ be? Does this work for higher degree polynomials?

Comment: What’s a diffeomorphism in this situation? Do you mean differentiable in the complex sense, thus analytic? Or do you mean real-differentiable?

Comment: @Lubin: In the complex sense i.e. analytic with analytic inverse. In my defence, I did write "entire" above.

Comment: Well, then you should ask yourself what the analytic isomorphisms of the complex plane are.

Comment: @Lubin: Oh dear! Good point. That's really an answer. Would it be rude for me to ask about homeomorphisms instead in order to give the question some sense?

Comment: @Lubin: I have edited. Sorry to have changed the question so abruptly.

Comment: You did it very gracefully, I would say. Now I have no idea, without thinking of it more deeply than I have time for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I thought about it some more and I think the answer is no.

> **Easy fact:** Let $q : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be a function, let $f,g$ be bijections of $\mathbb{C}$ and let $c \in \mathbb{C}$. Then $g(q(f(z))) = g(c)$ has as many solutions as $q(z) = c$. In fact, $f$ puts the solution sets in bijection.

Now, notice that $z^3 = 0$ has precisely one solution. That means that, for any function of the form $p(z) = g(f(z)^3)$ where $f,g$ are bijections, there should exist a $c \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $p(z) = c$ has exactly one solution.

However the above does not occur for all degree three polynomials. Consider for instance $p(z) = z^3 + 3z^2$. Let $c \in \mathbb{C}$. The equation $p(z) = c$ will have three solutions unless the discriminant $\Delta_c = 27(4-c)c$ of $p(z) - c$ vanishes. So $p(z) = c$ only has less than three solutions when $c=0$ or $4$. In each of these cases, $p(z) = c$ has two solutions. Thus, it is not even possible to find discontinuous bijections $f,g : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $g(f(z)^3) = z^3 + 3z^2$.

Comment: In fact the only polynomials $p$ of degree $n$ with the property that there exists $c \in \mathbb C$ such that $p(z) = c$ has exactly one solution are those of the form $b (z - a)^n + c$.  Thus you can only "complete the $n$'th power" when you can do it with translation.

Comment: @Robert: Oh yeah, for some reason I wasn't thinking about this very clearly. If $p(z) = c$ has one solution, then $p(z) - c$ has one root $a$ of order $n = \operatorname{deg}(p)$ i.e. $p(z) -c = b(z-a)^n$ for some $b \neq 0$. So, yes. As you say, $p(z) = b(z-a)^n + c$. This should have been clear to me.